# creating variables from elements in different rows of data frame

Tags: r

I've been struggling to create a few variables in my data frame that looks like this:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(unit = c('A','B','C','A','B','C','D'),location = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), value.X = c('5','6', '4', '3','10', '7','3'),value.Y = c('1','4','7','9','4','6','4'),team = c('A / B', 'A / B', 'C' , 'A', 'B / C', 'B / C','D'),team.B = c('A / C ', 'A / C', 'B', 'A / B / D', 'A / B / D', 'C', 'A / B / D'),supra = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A / C / D', 'B', 'A / C / D' , 'A / C / D'),pos.supra = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1))

  unit location value.X value.Y  team    team.B     supra pos.supra
1    A        1       5       1 A / B    A / C          A         1
2    B        1       6       4 A / B     A / C         B         2
3    C        1       4       7     C         B         C         3
4    A        2       3       9     A A / B / D A / C / D         1
5    B        2      10       4 B / C A / B / D         B         2
6    C        2       7       6 B / C         C A / C / D         1
7    D        2       3       4     D A / B / D A / C / D         1
```

I need to create a variable that sums the difference between `value.X` and `value.Y` for the units that are in `team.B` that are not in `team` and are not in `supra`. AND `pos.supra.1` that is either number one or immediately below if the unit in question has `pos.supra.1` equals to one. I need this for each `unit` in each `location`. I know there are too many steps, so here is a more detailed description. Maybe you can skip or reverse the order of these steps. It doesn't matter.

( 1 ) find the `supra` team that is number one or below (if unit has `supra` with `pos.supra` equals to `1`)

```
supra.I.need = c('B','A','A','B','A / C / D', 'B','B')
```

( 2 ) Check who in `who.I.need` are not in `team` but are in `team.B`:

```
that.is.not.in.team.but.are.in.team.B = c('NA','NA','NA','B', 'A,D','NA','B')
```

( 3 ) Finally, calculate the difference between `value.Y` and `value.X` of all units in the variable above and sum them up (note I sum the delta for `A` and `D`):

```
delta = c('NA','NA','NA','8','2','NA','8')
```

Thus, the final data frame should look like this:

```
df.2 <- data.frame(unit = c('A','B','C','A','B','C','D'),location = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), value.X = c('5','6', '4', '3','10', '7','3'),value.Y = c('1','4','7','9','4','6','4'),team = c('A / B', 'A / B', 'C' , 'A', 'B / C', 'B / C','D'),team.B = c('A / C ', 'A / C', 'B', 'A / B / D', 'A / B / D', 'C', 'A / B / D'),supra = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A / C / D', 'B', 'A / C / D' , 'A / C / D'),pos.supra = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1),supra.I.need = c('B','A','A','B','A / C / D', 'B','B'),that.is.not.in.team.but.are.in.team.B = c('NA','NA','NA','B', 'A,D','NA','B'),delta = c('NA','NA','NA','8','2','NA','8'))

  unit location value.X value.Y  team    team.B     supra pos.supra supra.I.need that.is.not.in.team.but.are.in.team.B delta
1    A        1       5       1 A / B    A / C          A         1            B                                    NA    NA
2    B        1       6       4 A / B     A / C         B         2            A                                    NA    NA
3    C        1       4       7     C         B         C         3            A                                    NA    NA
4    A        2       3       9     A A / B / D A / C / D         1            B                                     B     8
5    B        2      10       4 B / C A / B / D         B         2    A / C / D                                   A,D     2
6    C        2       7       6 B / C         C A / C / D         1            B                                    NA    NA
7    D        2       3       4     D A / B / D A / C / D         1            B                                     B     8
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have a search through Stackoverflow, for `subset` and `data.table` with tag `[r]`

Comment: Wait you can use R to subset data???

Comment: It's good that you tried to break down the process but I suggest you post a generic question or explain your data better. Your current nomenclature and usage of verbs is very confusing.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I did not make it clearer. @RicardoSaporta, Señor O, I did my homework before posting the question, but I could not find an answer that could completely solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one go at it.  Most of this is creating variables or matching on multiple outcomes and subsetting with `%in%`.  I got bogged down on the last step and so a loop was an easy out.  I annotated the code a bit to show what I was doing.

Do note that all of this is working with character vectors by using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the data.frame.  I'm not sure why your numeric vectors are all entered as character vectors, but if that's not what your actual dataset is like you can avoid the need for `as.numeric`.

```
require(plyr)
# create the supra needed when pos.supra is 1 or not
df1 = ddply(df.1, .(location), transform,
        needed = ifelse(pos.supra == 1, supra[pos.supra == 2], supra[pos.supra == 1]) )

# break apart the teams into lists for team, team.B, needed
    # the result is a list
# strsplit needs character vectors, not factors
team = strsplit(df1$team, " / ")
teamb = strsplit(df1$team.B, " / ")
needs = strsplit(as.character(df1$needed), " / ")

# pull out everything in team b that's not in team
b.not.team = mapply(function(x, y) x[!x %in% y], teamb, team)

# now match needed supra and everything in team b but not team and
    # paste together the results with a comma between and put in df1
df1$bneeded = mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x[x %in% y], collapse = ","), needs, b.not.team)


for (i in 1:nrow(df1) ){
    matchto = unlist(strsplit(df1$bneeded[i], ","))
    diffs = as.numeric(df1$value.X[df1$unit %in% matchto]) -
        as.numeric(df1$value.Y[df1$unit %in% matchto])
    df1$delta[i] = sum(diffs)
}

df1$bneeded[df1$bneeded == ""] = NA
df1$delta[df1$delta == 0] = NA
df1
```

** Edit for loop alternative **
Here's an alternative to a loop to create the differences between x and y.  Sometimes all you need is a new morning to realize what's wrong in your code. ;)  I like loops in many situations because it can be easy to read what is going on in the code.  In this case, I used `mapply` throughout the rest of the code and so here is the `mapply` option.

```
df1$diffxy = mapply(function(x, y) sum(as.numeric(df1$value.X[x %in% y])) - 
                    sum(as.numeric(df1$value.Y[x %in% y])),
      df1["unit"], strsplit(df1$bneeded, ","))
```